# vhdl signal assignment in a testbench

Tags: signals, vhdl

Even after doing an extensive research in the web, I have not come across a clean explanation of how signal assignment happens in a vhdl testbench with wait statements.

Could somebody please elaborate how does it work?

For e.g. within the process I have something like this:

```
wait until spi_sck = '1';
wait until spi_sck = '0';
tb_rx_bytes(7) <= spi_mosi;
```

How can I make sure the `tb_rx_byte` assignment happens?

More specifically, my problem is that the last `tb_rx_bytes` does not get set to the `spi_mosi` assignment.

```
for j in 31 downto 0 loop
  wait until spi_sck = '1';
  wait until spi_sck = '0';
  tb_rx_bytes(j) <= spi_mosi;
end loop;
```

Comment: How are you determining that the assignment has not happened? There's nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: I'm guessing that immediately after this you check the value of tb_rx_bytes. You'll get the wrong (or more accurately, the old) value for the final byte because the pending signal assignment (all signal assignments within a process are pending until a wait statement is encountered or the process ends) hasn't been committed because no wait statement has appeared since you did the assignment.

Comment: Note that there is no difference in signal assignment behaviour between testbench code and synthesizable code, although most wait statements (particularly those using explicit time like `wait for 5 ns`) can not be synthesized.

Comment: This isn't a  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and raises the question of SCK polarity where the idle state for SCK may be high missing the last j bit. If you're not going to show more code, show waveforms.

Answer (score 1):

In order to see the effect of your signal assignment 3 conditions must hold successively:

1. there is an event (value change) on `spi_sck` and the new value is `'1'`
2. there is an event (value change) on `spi_sck` and the new value is `'0'`
3. some physical time elapses such that the assignment has a visible effect

I guess it is the last condition that fails and prevents the last assignment from having visible effects. Add a `wait for 1 ns;` after your `end loop;` statement.

Comment: Corollary to point (1): be careful with `wait until spi_sck = '1';` : if spi_sck is already '1' when you get here, nothing will happen until the *next* rising edge of spi_clk...

Comment: You only need to `wait` for 0 ns

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the things which confuses some people when they start working with VHDL, particularly those with a background in programming languages. In VHDL, signal assignments are not updated immediately like programming languages. Instead, the assignments are booked, and the signal values are updated when the process suspends. That happens when

1. The process runs to its end, and then waits for one of the signals in its sensitively list to change. or
2. When it encounters a wait statement.

So, in your case the value of tb_rx_bytes will be updated except bit 0, which is only booked for update in the last iteration of the loop. But the value is not updated, until one of the two conditions mentioned above are met.